# How to install progresql-9.3 properly

Tags: postgresql

I followed the installation on this document http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/ and every thing seems to be fine. But when I try to this follow this tutorial: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-createdb.html, everything is not fine any more. This is the error I got when I try to create a database table:

```
$ createdb mydb
WARNING: password file "/home/.../.pgpass" has group or world access; permissions should     be u=rw (0600) or less
WARNING: password file "/home/.../.pgpass" has group or world access; permissions should be u=rw (0600) or less
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "..." does not exist


$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb mydb
bash: /usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb: No such file or directory
```

Comment: those commands should be run inside the postgreSQL console, not in bash

Comment: Read the error message! Your .pgpass file has incorrect permissions and in addition seems to have wrong contents (unless you are genuinely trying to connect as user '...').

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert `createdb` has to be run in bash, it's not a SQL statement. `create database`would be a SQL statement to be run in `psql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I stand corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You got one warning and one error.

- You can handle the warning by this command of line in your terminal:

  ```
  $ chmod 600 ~/.pgpass
  ```
- When you write "psql" in your terminal, Postgres DBMS try to connect to the one database with your computer name but it can't find it. In other hand Postgrest create a database named "postgres" when it install so try connect to this and create your database. You can connect to "postgres" database easily with this command:

  ```
  $ psql postgres
  ```
- If you get the "connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?" error start your database with this command:

  ```
  $ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
  ```
- Check the result with this command:

  ```
  $ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you what's wrong. Change the permissions on `.pgpass`:

```
chmod u=rw $HOME/.pgpass
```

Also, unless you edited the error message and didn't say so, you appear to actually be attempting to connect as user `...`. I imagine the examples you read said something like:

```
psql -U "..." template1
```

and assumed you'd replace "..." with the *actual username*.